# Does the name of parameter have to be model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding, model

Hit a strange issue where my model is not binding and shows up on the controller as null.

I have a form doing a httppost. My breakpoint in the controller is hit and the parameter I expect to be my model is null.

Looking at some example code on another page that works, I copied and pasted it and the only difference was the name of the parameter was 'model' instead of message.

View

```
@model Site.Models.ContactMessage

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>ContactMessage</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Message, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.To, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.To, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.To, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contact(ContactMessage message)
    {
        var m = message;
        return View();
    }
```

and it worked. I thought I must have entirely missed something about naming convention. Found you can use Bind, from reading a heap of other posts, to change the prefix like;

```
    public ActionResult Contact([Bind(Prefix = "model")] ContactMessage message)
```

but that didn't work, still null. Going to rename it to model so it works and I can move on but would like to know why it's not binding if not called model.

```
    public ActionResult Contact(ContactMessage message)
```

Changed back to this as above but still returns a null. 
Interestingly, if I open up another MVC app, that one has whatever parameter names I want and works fine. It's using an older version of MVC 5 (not updated it yet but I will do that and see if anything happens. I don't expect it will.)

Comment: I tried newing up an instance of ContactMessage, setting the field and passing that to the view. It populated the field as I expected. Changing the value and submitting still returns a null unless the name of the variable is model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you model contains a property named `Message` and you also have a parameter named `message` The `DefaultModelBinder` reads the form values which will include `message = "someTextValue"` and searches for model properties that have the name `message`. It finds the one in you model and sets it value (all OK so far) but then it finds another one (your parameter) and tries to set the value of a complex object `string` value (in effect `ContactMessage message = "someTextValue";`) which fails so the model becomes `null`

Comment: Sounds plausible. Thanks!