# What would make an MVC5 form POST break link with Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a project that uses a couple of forms to post to an action using 2 similar models. I copied the first of the views that I worked on that was found to be working, changed names inside to fit the other model, changed all the references in all places. Yet, when doing a post, the model comes out as null. In worst case I'll just have to go through the form collection and rebuild the model - but what exactly is the difference that would simply make my POST break the link with its model?

Comment: We need to see your code.

Comment: I'll try to provide an example , but are there any very basic reasons why posting from a form would break this link ?

Comment: Yes, but there are far too many to list in a comment here without further contextual information.

Comment: Okay I will see what I can put here tomorrow!

Comment: Looking at this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968452/model-is-null-when-form-submitted) , I have got an idea for a test to run tomorrow morning. I do remember that in this model the difference from the working model was that it indeed has a '.Store' property, and in my [HttpPost] I do have a parameter which goes like ActionResult MyFunction(MyStore store) - maybe it's messing it up!

Comment: Based on your last comment, refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114024/does-the-name-of-parameter-have-to-be-model/32559991#32559991)

Answer (score 0):

According to the answers [Does the name of parameter have to be model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114024/does-the-name-of-parameter-have-to-be-model/32559991#32559991) and [Model is null when form submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968452/model-is-null-when-form-submitted) , and after testing, the answer is indeed that having a property with the same name as the variable that's passed into a controller action will do this. Thanks!